# How to convert TRON address to different format

Tags: blockchain, tron

I have an issue while deploying contract in TRON network, where I am required to specify address in format that starts with 4.. or when I receive transactions history (here the api respond with 4.. addresses as well).

Therefore I have a question:

How to convert TRON address started with **T**LAXtqju7GKyqoP... to **4**19b6e043089843624c36f1e3b1e8572d189cbe170 and vice versa?

Answer (score 5):

How to convert TRON address started with TLAXtqju7GKyqoP... to 419b6e043089843624c36f1e3b1e8572d189cbe170 and vice versa?

```
const TronWeb = require('tronweb');
const tronWeb = new TronWeb(
  'http://127.0.0.1:9090',
  'http://127.0.0.1:9090',
  'http://127.0.0.1:9090',
  'd6fbbf6eecffdb32172e391363a401f89617acb9dd01897b9fa180830a8a46b2',
);
```

*Once you have the tronWeb object, then you can convert the addresses vice-versa by using tronWeb's address utility*

```
For Example:
const addressInHexFormat = '414450cf8c8b6a8229b7f628e36b3a658e84441b6f';
const addressInBase58 = tronWeb.address.fromHex(addressInHexFormat);
> addressInBase58 = 'TGCRkw1Vq759FBCrwxkZGgqZbRX1WkBHSu'
const addressInHex = tronWeb.address.toHex(addressInBase58);
> addressInHex = '414450cf8c8b6a8229b7f628e36b3a658e84441b6f'
```

**Note**

*The above tronWeb object is created by using Tron's Quickstart Docker container. In this way the addresses can be converted vice-versa.*

Answer (score 1):

You just should decode your base58Address from Base58. In result you will obtain addresschecksum, so you should remove last 4 bytes from result and obtain desired address.

```
address = 41||sha3[12,32): 415a523b449890854c8fc460ab602df9f31fe4293f 
sha256_0 = sha256(address): 06672d677b33045c16d53dbfb1abda1902125cb3a7519dc2a6c202e3d38d3322 
sha256_1 = sha256(sha256_0): 9b07d5619882ac91dbe59910499b6948eb3019fafc4f5d05d9ed589bb932a1b4 
checkSum = sha256_1[0, 4): 9b07d561 
addchecksum = address || checkSum: 415a523b449890854c8fc460ab602df9f31fe4293f9b07d561 
base58Address = Base58(addchecksum): TJCnKsPa7y5okkXvQAidZBzqx3QyQ6sxMW
```

Answer (score 1):

The address format is well explained in [the relevant TRON documentation](https://github.com/tronprotocol/documentation/blob/master/TRX/Tron-overview.md#62-mainnet-addresses-begin-with-41).

In Java code (based on [wallet-cli](https://github.com/tronprotocol/wallet-cli)):

```
public String tronHex(String base58) {
    byte[] decoded = decode58(base58);
    String hexString = decoded == null ? "" : org.spongycastle.util.encoders.Hex.toHexString(decoded);
    return hexString;
}


private byte[] decode58(String input) {
    byte[] decodeCheck = Base58.decode(input);
    if (decodeCheck.length <= 4) {
        return null;
    }
    byte[] decodeData = new byte[decodeCheck.length - 4];
    System.arraycopy(decodeCheck, 0, decodeData, 0, decodeData.length);
    byte[] hash0 = Sha256Hash.hash(decodeData);
    byte[] hash1 = Sha256Hash.hash(hash0);
    if (hash1[0] == decodeCheck[decodeData.length] &&
            hash1[1] == decodeCheck[decodeData.length + 1] &&
            hash1[2] == decodeCheck[decodeData.length + 2] &&
            hash1[3] == decodeCheck[decodeData.length + 3]) {
        return decodeData;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**And the other way around:**

```
public String hexStringTobBase58(String hexString) {
    hexString = adjustHex(hexString);
    byte[] decodedHex = hexString == null? new byte[0] : org.spongycastle.util.encoders.Hex.decode(hexString);
    String base58 = encode58(decodedHex);
    return base58;
}

private String adjustHex(String hexString) {
    if (hexString.startsWith("0x")) {
        hexString = "41" + hexString.substring(2);
    }
    if (hexString.length() % 2 == 1) {
        hexString = "0" + hexString;
    }
    return hexString;
}


private String encode58(byte[] input) {
    byte[] hash0 = Sha256Hash.hash(input);
    byte[] hash1 = Sha256Hash.hash(hash0);
    byte[] inputCheck = new byte[input.length + 4];
    System.arraycopy(input, 0, inputCheck, 0, input.length);
    System.arraycopy(hash1, 0, inputCheck, input.length, 4);
    return Base58.encode(inputCheck);
}
```

Find class `Base58` [here](https://github.com/tronprotocol/lever/blob/master/src/main/java/org/tron/common/utils/Base58.java), class `Sha256Hash` [here](https://github.com/tronprotocol/lever/blob/master/src/main/java/org/tron/common/utils/Sha256Hash.java) and the required dependency to Spongy Castle [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.madgag.spongycastle/core).

Comment: Thanks for the complete solution. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

C# example:

```
        public static string GetHex(this String str)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            var bytes = Base58.Bitcoin.Decode(str); // nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleBase/

            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length - 4; i++)
            {
                var t = bytes[i];
                sb.Append(t.ToString("X2"));
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Python example

```
import base58
import hashlib

def sha256(msg):
    return hashlib.sha256(bytes.fromhex(msg)).hexdigest()

class TronConverter:
    @staticmethod
    def to_hex(address: str) -> str:
        """TRON address to EVM address"""
        return "0x" + base58.b58decode(address).hex()[2:-8]

    @staticmethod
    def from_hex(address: str) -> str:
        """EVM address to TRON address"""
        addr = '41' + address[2:]
        doubleSha256 = sha256(sha256(addr))
        checkSum = doubleSha256[:8]
        _address = bytes.fromhex(addr + checkSum)
        return base58.b58encode(_address).decode()
```

Usage:

```
evm_wallet = TronConverter.to_hex("TXXmULCEzRo6JfxUP1LYfmzbiKUezUvUNj")
# 0xec830e98468d23f54c58174bb9a3671fcc440ff2

tron_wallet = TronConverter.from_hex("0xec830e98468d23f54c58174bb9a3671fcc440ff2")
# TXXmULCEzRo6JfxUP1LYfmzbiKUezUvUNj
```

I also uploaded the [tron-address-converter](https://pypi.org/project/tron-address-converter/) to PyPi

Installation:

```
pip install tron-address-converter
```

Usage:

```
from tron_address_converter import TronConverter

evm_wallet = TronConverter.to_hex("TXXmULCEzRo6JfxUP1LYfmzbiKUezUvUNj")
# 0xec830e98468d23f54c58174bb9a3671fcc440ff2

tron_wallet = TronConverter.from_hex("0xec830e98468d23f54c58174bb9a3671fcc440ff2") 
# TXXmULCEzRo6JfxUP1LYfmzbiKUezUvUNj
```